# Gnuplot plot don't fill canvas

Tags: shell, gnuplot

I'm checking results of my simulation.
I need to do 2d maps of a 3d surfaces. I did a lot of times in the past with gnuplot.

I created a script to do it faster:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set term pdf size 600, 400
set output "Corr_57res_1bpi.pdf"
set view map
set xrange [0:20000]
set yrange [20:221]
set cbrange [-1:1]
set ylabel "Temperatures"
set xlabel "Number of seqs"
#set clabel "Delta correlation"
set title "Delta Correlation"
plot 'corr_57res_1bpi.dat' u 1:2:3  w image
```

The input file has this format:

```
10000 102 0.710468
1000 102 0.672530
20000 102 0.709955
5000 102 0.702273
10000 20 0.512186
1000 20 0.485288
20000 20 0.487161
5000 20 0.506256
10000 221 0.636247
1000 221 0.559779
20000 221 0.621900
5000 221 0.614103
...
```

Last time I used this script (like 1 month ago) i obtained a correct 2d maps that fill the border of the canvas.

Now I'm retry to do it and i obtained this result:
[Wrong results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wFJb.png)

I tried to fix the code, but nothing happens, also i tried to update gnuplot to 5.2.5 (i had 5.0 previously) but nothing happens. Also the other typse of plot work perfectly.
I'm running out of ideas, so i hope you can help me.
Regards
Matteo

Answer (score 1):

For the `with image` style, the "bounding box" of the generated image is initialized in `src/graphics.c` as:

```
  p_start_corner[0] = points[0].x;
  p_start_corner[1] = points[0].y;
  p_end_corner[0] = points[p_count-1].x;
  p_end_corner[1] = points[p_count-1].y;
```

This effectively means that the first and last point of your data file determine the entire "range" of the plot. You could make the script more robust by sorting the data first in order not to rely on the order of the records in the data file itself:

```
set view map
set xrange [0:20000]
set yrange [20:221]
set cbrange [-1:1]
set ylabel "Temperatures"
set xlabel "Number of seqs"
#set clabel "Delta correlation"
set title "Delta Correlation"
plot '<sort -k1,1n -k2,2n corr_57res_1bpi.dat' u 1:2:3 w image
```